# Collection<? extends T> means?

Tags: java

Why is it throwing compilation error at line 23. **'a'** is an object of class Apple and **col** is a list containing Apple objects, but still, it is throwing a compilation error mentioned below:

*The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Fruit) in the type Collection is not applicable for the arguments (Fruit)*

```
public class Basket {
    List<Fruit> list;
    public Basket() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public Basket(List<Fruit> plist) {
        list = plist;
    }

   void addFruit(Collection<? extends Fruit> col) { // this does not work
// void addFruit(Collection<Fruit> col) { // this works
        Fruit a = new Apple();
        Apple a1 = new Apple();
        Fruit f1 = new Fruit();
        col.add(a);// line 23
    }

    int getSize() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit f1 = new Apple();
        Fruit f2 = new Apple();
        Fruit f3 = new Apple();
        List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(f1);
        list.add(f2);
        list.add(f3);
        Basket b = new Basket(list);
        b.addFruit(list);
        System.out.println(b.getSize());
    }
}

class Fruit {
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
}
```

Comment: What compilation error is it throwing?

Comment: Better than throwing `ClassCastException` at runtime :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collection<? extends Fruit> col` means that `col` is a `Collection` of `Fruit` or a `Collection` of some sub-class of `Fruit`, such as `Collection<Apple>` or `Collection<Banana>`.

You can't add an `Apple` to a `Collection` that might be a `Collection<Banana>`.

If you want to be able to add any `Fruit`, change the signature to:

```
void addFruit(Collection<Fruit> col)
```

Comment: Collection<Fruit> does work but, Collection<? extends Fruit> also means the same right. When should  Collection<? extends Fruit> be used?

Comment: @user2833621 No, it doesn't mean the same. `Collection<? extends Fruit>` is used when you wish to pass a Collection of one type of Fruit, but you don't want to specify the exact type. It allows you to pass a `Collection<Apple>` or a `Collection<Banana> or a `Collection<Fruit>` to that method. If you change it to `Collection<Fruit>`, you can't pass a `Collection<Apple>` or a `Collection<Banana>` to that method, only a `Collection<Fruit>`.

Answer (score 0):

A collection can only contain entries of some type and its subtypes. For example if you have a `Collection<Banana>`, it can only contain bananas.

Even though `Banana` is a sub-class of `Fruit`, `Collection<Banana>` is not type-compatible with `Collection<Fruit>`. It might seem a bit counter-intuitive, but think of it this way: In a `Collection<Banana>` you only expect a `Banana`. You don't expect an `Apple`. But if you have a `Collection<Fruit>`, you can have all sorts of fruit in it. And you can add any fruit to the collection.

If you cast your `Collection<Banana>` to `Collection<Fruit>`, you can add apples in it. Then you try to pull a banana out of your `Collection<Banana>` and you get an apple. Since you cannot cast `Apple` to `Banana`, a `ClassCastException` is thrown at runtime and your code fails.

So, in your case, you probably want a `Collection<Fruit>` as suggested by @Eran. However, to answer your question in detail: If you had a `Collection<Banana>`, you could use the collection as `Collection<? extends Fruit>`, but you are limited to methods that don't have generic input param.

For example you can mutate the collection using `retainAll`, `remove` and a few others, you can as well as use all read-only operations, but you can't `add` new apples to your collection of bananas.